# How do i get modified hill equation starting values?

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

How can I get starting values?
I think there is a problem with the slope
I know the model is modified hill equation
logFC_max is upper bound(5) - lower bound(-1)
Smax is the maximum sensitivity(1/EC50) of the gene
tmax is the point in time with maximum sensitivity
Sdur represents a measure of the duration of the sensitivity interval.

```r
 head(ctr)
  t c   y    logy logc      logt
1 1 0 100 4.60517 -Inf 0.0000000
2 1 0 100 4.60517 -Inf 0.0000000
3 1 0 100 4.60517 -Inf 0.0000000
4 2 0 100 4.60517 -Inf 0.6931472
5 2 0 100 4.60517 -Inf 0.6931472
6 2 0 100 4.60517 -Inf 0.6931472

(time <- unique(ctr$t))
 [1]  1  2  4  6  8 24 30 48 54 72

fo <- logy ~ logFC_max / (1+exp(-slope*(log(c)-log(1/(s_max*exp(-0.5*(log(t)-log(t_max))/s_dur)^2)))))

ctr_nls <- nls(fo,
               data = ctr,
               start = list(logFC_max = 6, slope = -10, s_max = 4.619, t_max = 72, s_dur = 8))
```

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In log(1/(s_max * exp(-0.5 * ((log(t) - log(t_max))/s_dur)^2))) :
>     NaNs produced